# Javascript: call method itself inside a method (with original parameters)

Tags: javascript, node.js

i develop a class to upload a file to imageshack. For this you have to do a authorization first to get a auth_id.

Because of i use this in nodejs i don't want to create the auth_id every time i upload a image. For that i need something like this:

```
function test(){
  this.auth = "";
}

// Callback will execute when file-upload is finish
test.prototype.upload = function(file, callback) {
   if(this.auth == "") {
       /*** HERE I NEED HELP: ***/
       this.make_auth(this.upload(file,callback));
   }else{
     // Do upload and then
     callback();
   }
}

test.prototype.make_auth = function(callback) {
    // Make auth...
    this.auth = "01020312032";
    callback();
}
```

What i want to do:
- Check if this.auth is set
- If this.auth == "" make the auth and call the upload-function again after finish with the original parameters

How i can do this?

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
this.make_auth(this.upload(_paramters));
```

To something like:

```
var self = this;
this.make_auth(function() { self.upload(_paramters); });
```

You should probably be passing a possible `err` to your callback in `make_auth` in case authentication fails.